# What is *.o file?

Tags: c++

I'm compiling own project. And it halted by this error:

> LINK||fatal error LNK1181: cannot open
>   input file
>   'obj\win\release\src\lua\bindings.o'|

Compiling using Code::Blocks with VS 2005/2008 compiler under win7.
There are also lot of another empty directories where *.o files are missing.

What do they do?

Comment: First, a '.o' file is an intermediate stage between compiling and linking.  If there are compilation errors, VS 2008 will not generate a '.o' file, but will still continue to try and build the application, failing after the linking stage.  When flustered, you can always try a "Rebuild All"; however, I recommend researching error logs for missing object files.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

A file ending in .o is an *object file*. The compiler creates an object file for each source file, before linking them together, into the final executable.

Comment: Hm, what reasons can be here? Why compiler doesn't made object-files for all need sources?

Comment: A compiler can't make an object file for source it doesn't have.

Comment: Can be a lot of reasons. Most likely you messed up some inclusions or messed up a template. It could also be some linker-setting which is wrong, but I doubt that :)

Comment: for ocktonal : it's probably easier to manage smaller files instead of one huge object file in case of problems.

Comment: @Ockonal, review the **entire** output log from the compiler.  Visual Studio 2008 has a habit of linking files and trying to build an executable when there are earlier compilation errors causing files not to be translated into ".o" (object) files.

Comment: Why does it do that?

Answer (score 63):

You've gotten some answers, and most of them are correct, but miss what (I think) is probably the point here.

My guess is that you have a makefile you're trying to use to create an executable. In case you're not familiar with them, makefiles list dependencies between files. For a really simple case, it might have something like:

```
myprogram.exe: myprogram.o
    $(CC) -o myprogram.exe myprogram.o

myprogram.o: myprogram.cpp
    $(CC) -c myprogram.cpp
```

The first line says that `myprogram.exe` depends on `myprogram.o`. The second line tells how to create `myprogram.exe` *from* `myprogram.o`. The third and fourth lines say `myprogram.o` depends on `myprogram.cpp`, and how to create `myprogram.o` from `myprogram.cpp` respectively.

My guess is that in your case, you have a makefile like the one above that was created for gcc. The problem you're running into is that you're using it with MS VC instead of gcc. As it happens, MS VC uses ".obj" as the extension for its object files instead of ".o".

That means when make (or its equivalent built into the IDE in your case) tries to build the program, it looks at those lines to try to figure out how to build `myprogram.exe`. To do that, it sees that it needs to build `myprogram.o`, so it looks for the rule that tells it how to build `myprogram.o`. That says it should compile the .cpp file, so it does that.

Then things break down -- the VC++ compiler produces `myprogram.obj` instead of `myprogram.o` as the object file, so when it tries to go to the next step to produce `myprogram.exe` from `myprogram.o`, it finds that its attempt at creating `myprogram.o` simply failed. It did what the rule said to do, but that didn't produce `myprogram.o` as promised. It doesn't know what to do, so it quits and give you an error message.

The cure for that *specific* problem is probably pretty simple: edit the make file so all the object files have an extension of `.obj` instead of `.o`. There's room for a lot of question whether that will fix everything though -- that may be all you need, or it may simply lead to other (probably more difficult) problems.

Comment: So $(CC) is for compiler?

Comment: @zygimantus: yes. In theory it's the C compiler, but at least in most cases the C and C++ compilers are the same binary (which sorts out the language based on the extension of the file being compiled).

Comment: I replaced all my `.o` extensions with `.obj`, but now the same error is happening: `make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [src/haproxy.obj] Error 2
`

Comment: Such a good answer, this example let me understand basic makefiles better than a book. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

A .o object file file (also .obj on Windows) contains compiled object code (that is, machine code produced by your C or C++ compiler), together with the names of the functions and other objects the file contains. Object files are processed by the **linker** to produce the final executable. If your build process has not produced these files, there is probably something wrong with your makefile/project files.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to note that *object files* are assembled to binary code in a format that is *relocatable*. This is a form which allows the assembled code to be loaded anywhere into memory for use with other programs by a *linker*.

Instructions that refer to labels will not yet have an address assigned for these labels in the *.o* file.

These labels will be written as '0' and the assembler creates a relocation record for these unknown addresses. When the file is linked and output to an executable the unknown addresses are resolved and the program can be executed.

You can use the *nm* tool on an object file to list the symbols defined in a .o file.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct.  More specifically, an .o (.obj) -- or *object file* is a single source file compiled in to machine code (*I'm not sure if the "machine code" is the same or similar to an executable machine code*). Ultimately, it's an intermediate between an executable program and plain-text source file.

The linker uses the o files to assemble the file executable.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) may have more detailed information. I'm not sure how much info you'd like or need.

Comment: For future reference: "Ink-Jet"'s answer is this - the user has since changed their name - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186252/13580938