# What are .o files for in gcc command?

Tags: c, makefile

```
gcc -o file1 file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

I don't have much experience with C and have found the above in a `Makefile` on our systems.

What are `.o` files and what is file1.o in this scenario?  Is it related to `file1`?

Comment: .o file means gcc create object file

Comment: When you compile a source file (.c), it generats an object file (.o). In this scenario, it links 3 object files file1.o, file2.o, file3.o to create an executable file `file1`.

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn is `file1.o` the object file that has just been created?

Comment: Your Question and Description of the question does not match. Change .o to -o in question.

Comment: There are 2 phases: 1) compile souce files to create object files and 2) link object files and lib to create executable file. `file1.o` is generated when compile file1.c

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn Why isn't the first step in the Makefile?  Is it just assumed to compile `file1.c`?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't in the first step in the Makefile. But it has to compile the source files somewhere else. You can specify the output object name, but the default is same as source file name.

Answer (score 1):

**-o file**

Place output in file `file`. This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

Since only one output file can be specified, it does not make sense to use '-o' when compiling more than one input file, unless you are producing an executable file as output.

Here executable file produced is `file1`

If '-o' is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler file in source.s, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

.o files are compiled object file of your c code file.

Qouted here -> [GCC Command-Line Options](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html)

Answer (score 1):

> A file ending in .o is an object file. The compiler creates an object file for each source file, before linking them together, into the final executable.

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186246/what-is-o-file).

Answer (score 0):

They are [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file).

Quoting from the [gcc online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix ‘.c’, ‘.i’, ‘.s’, etc., with ‘.o’.