# C++ doesn't create text file

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

I'm new to the StackOverFlow.

I'm using Dev-C++ and I wanted to write a text file with my C++ program. But the problem is my program doesn't create a text file.

Instead it creates a file named "**026.Writing-to-Files-With-Ofstream.o**". (My cpp file's name is: **026.Writing-to-Files-With-Ofstream.cpp**)

That's not what I wanted.

Also Dev-C++ doesn't give me any errors or warnings.

I tried using CodeBlocks and still the same result. It creates a ".o" file and not a text file.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(){
    std::ofstream file ("hello.txt");
    file << "Hello There!"; //line 5
    file.open("hello.txt"); //line 6

    return 0;
}
```

I tried everything. Nothing in the desktop or in my working directory. I switched the lines (5 and 6). I really need your help.

Comment: You have compiled the cpp-file. You need to link it and then actually *run* it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186246/what-is-o-file

Comment: Line 6 should close the file instead of opening it - you have already opened it on line 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it!** I searched all the Windows files/folders with the search option on the start menu. It took a long time (10 mins) but i finally found out where the file was. It was in the inside of a folder named "VTRoot". Thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

You do too much.

```
std::ofstream file ("hello.txt");
```

This line creates ofstream and opens it for writing. When the stream is opened for writing, it's contents on disk is emptied!

```
file << "Hello There!";
```

This like prints something to the ofstream. Usually, it is stored in the buffer not yet saved to disk or displayed on screen. (To actually save something to disk, you need `endl`, `flush`, or to close the file. The file is closed when the block where it was opened ends, or when you close it explicitly.)

```
file.open("hello.txt"); //line 6
```

You again open the file for output, thus emptying it's contents on disk, and emptying the buffer.

```
}
```

whatever is in the buffer, saved to disk. But there is nothing in the buffer, because you opened the file again!

You should remove the line 6.

Comment: It didn't work.#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //file stream
int main(){
 std::ofstream file ("hello.txt");
 file << "Hello There!";
 file.close();
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: Did it create the file hello.txt ?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems here:

First, you just compiled the code so the output is a compiled object file called "026.Writing-to-Files-With-Ofstream.o". You need to run it.

Second, the code is not entirely correct. You already opened the file when you did `std::ofstream file("hello.txt");` so you do not need line 6. You need to open the file before writing to it. Also You need to close the file after you finished writting: `file.close();`

Comment: i'm on windows. so all i do is just clicking a button and it compiles and runs the program:

Comment: what button? please be more specific, give us more details.