# What's the point of compiling the source file corresponding to the C++ header into a .o file separately?

Tags: c++

What's the point of compiling the source file corresponding to the C++ header into a `.o`  file separately?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \*.o file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186246/what-is-o-file)

Comment: Are you referring to pch (pre-compiled header)?

Comment: Can you explain what you were asking? Did I misunderstand you (in my answer)?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think question's form comes from methodical concept of some frameworks and tutorials where one .cpp file always have corresponding .h file. The tutorials on those often are formulated so that user begins falsely believing that's it's the only way to organize a C++ program (and one tutorial I've read explicitly was stating so - but it wasn't ISO-compliant implementation).

Answer (score 2):

One reason is to reduce compilation time for programs spanning multiple files. If a file is changed, only that file and files that are dependent on it are needed to be recompiled. From a translation unit, the compiler generates an object file, which can be further processed and linked.

Another reason may be to reduce memory requirement on the compiler, since it only processes one translation unit at a time.

Yet another advantage of processing separate translations units is that the process can easily be parallelized.

See [translation unit wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))

Comment: What needs to be recompiled should not change with precompiling headers: The dependencies are exactly the same.

Comment: The question is not about precompiled headers. @Peter-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Java or C# don't have anything like translation units, everything in a project is compiled all at once, and they have no problem whatsoever with compilation times - they're generally much faster than in C++. The C/C++ way of doing things actually *hurts* compilation times, because header files are recompiled multiple times in every file where they're included. It's a lot of wasted work. Template instantiations are also needlessly compiled multiple times when used in multiple files, even if they have the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that large headers can dominate the compile time of source files: Most of the code compiled is not in your cpp file but in the headers it includes, your own or third party's.

The overhead resulting from the C/C++ system of including headers is large for two reasons: The same headers are included (and hence, compiled) over and over again; and on top they are often recompiled for no good reason since headers, the interface definition, tend to be more stable than cpp files, the implementation. The latter is most evident for system headers which do not change at all between compile runs.

Large headers can result from using templates — libraries like C++'s STL, boost or Loki often consist largely, and sometimes exclusively, of headers. Remember that headers can include each other so that the amount of code compiled is greater than meets the eye.

The gcc documentation [has a chapter](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) about precompiled headers that also discusses the background. Visual Studio has offered the option to use precompiled headers for a long time.

Comment: By *"long time"* you mean 23 years?

Comment: @PeterWood I have no idea. As long as I can remember. But I'll delete this answer soon because I misunderstood the OP.

Comment: Precompiled headers came in VC6 in 1998.

Comment: @PeterWood predates that by 4-5 years. At least Top Speed C++ had the feature. And precompiled headers were in VC4, 6.0 was different that it could precompile a unit, not just headers.

Answer (score 0):

***Short answer:***

Because ISO/IEC 14882 standard said so:

> The text of the program is kept in units called source files in this
> document. A source file together with all the headers and source files
> included via the preprocessing directive #include, less any source
> lines skipped by any of the conditional inclusion preprocessing
> directives, is called a translation unit. [Note 1: A C++ program need
> not all be translated at the same time. — end note]

> [Note 2: Previously translated translation units and instantiation
> units can be preserved individually or in libraries. The separate
> translation units of a program communicate ([basic.link]) by (for
> example) calls to functions whose identifiers have external or module
> linkage, manipulation of objects whose identifiers have external or
> module linkage, or manipulation of data files. Translation units can
> be separately translated and then later linked to produce an
> executable program. — end note]

***A somewhat longer answer:***

Separate source code files and their binary counterparts represent what is called translation units.

A translation unit is an organization unit formed at programmer's discretion and they can be used separately if proper program interfaces are used. Multiple compilation units aggregated into an archive of some sort are traditionally called "static library".

Dividing large programs to translation units limits memory required for compiler to process them, allows create independent tasks for compilation of separate units, reduces re-compilation time if only some source files were changes.

Each unit got a local name scope - file scope. In C and C++, if a function or variable declared as `static` in file scope, their linkage is *local*, i.e. nothing can use them from outside of this particular unit. Anything declared as `external` would have *global* linkage. This helped avoiding naming conflicts in C and was inherited by C++ as language feature, even while we have namespaces and public names now.

Translation units can be linked afterward, can be reused or linked in several combinations to produce separate programs. Implementation is allowed to perform link-time optimization on that stage, within limits allowed by as-if rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer for question, but it is good to know.

When you compile a header, all the macro values are fixed. This can introduce errors if you switch between, say, DEBUG/RELEASE builds, or in modules that change a macro value before including a header.

It is best to aggressively clean pre-compiled headers when switching builds, and only use them for stable header files, where the macro values are well-defined and fixed. Pre-compiled headers will probably disappear when C++ [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160) become well supported.