# Call a function from a cython generated .so file inside a c++ code

Tags: python, c++, c, cython, setuptools

My goal is to call python functions from C++. These python function must be compiled with cython in a .so file. The .so file must be the one that communicate with the c++ program.

Before all:

I am on Ubuntu, I am working with miniconda with python3.9.
I am in a folder (~/exp) made like this:

- exp

  - exp

    - __ init __.py
    - main.py
- setup.py
- run.cpp
- run.py

I translate the main.py to main.pyx, the file contains this code:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b

def entry_point():
    print(add(21,21))
```

I compiled this script with cython and obtained a .so file, with this setup.py script:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
   name='exp',
   ext_modules=cythonize("exp/main.pyx"),
   libraries=[('python3.9', {'include_dirs': ["~/miniconda3/include/python3.9"]})],
   library_dirs=['~/miniconda3/lib']
)
```

And this command:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Now I have a main.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so file in ~/exp/exp.

When I launch (run.py) which contains:

```
from exp.main import entry_point

if __name__ == "__main__":
    entry_point()
```

I have a normal behavior : It returns 42.

**Now, here come the problems**

I compile my run.cpp source, which contains :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "Python.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
   Py_Initialize();
   PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue, *presult;
   // Initialize the Python Interpreter
   Py_Initialize();

   // Build the name object
   pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"exp/main");

   // Load the module object
   pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);


   // pDict is a borrowed reference 
   pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);


   // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
   pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, (char*)"entry_point");

   Py_DECREF(pValue);

   // Clean up
   Py_DECREF(pModule);
   Py_DECREF(pName);
   Py_Finalize();
}
```

with the command :

```
g++ -Wall -I~/miniconda3/include/python3.9 run.cpp -L~/miniconda3/lib -lpython3.9 -o run.o -ldl
```

And then execute : ./run.o
To end with a beautiful :

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried with dlopen without success either.
Maybe I miss something, any help would be welcome.

Thank you :)

Comment: Compile the `.cpp` with `-g` to get debugging symbols. Then, do: `gdb ./run.o` to run under debugger. You _may_ need `--rpath` instead of or in addition to: `-L`. _Side note:_ Although in this instance it may not hurt, but, in general, _executable_ files should not end in `.o` (this extension is for _relocatable_ files). I might change things slightly so the `.cpp` file goes to `-o run` You can do: `ldd ./run` to see what `.so` the executable needs (and it will tell you whether it can find them).

Comment: You're completely missing error checking your c++ file - most Python functions return `NULL` to let you know if an exception occurred.

Comment: And `exp/main` is not a valid module path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thank you to [Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5382650/craig-estey) and [DavidW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657412/davidw) for their comments.

So I finally was able to make it work, two things was wrong:

1. pValue was not used, so the Py_DECREF raised an Error
2. the module path "exp/main" was indeed not valid, but "exp.main" was valid.

A very last thing. Something I omitted was the `PyObject_CallObject` that allows to call my `PyObject pFunc`.

I've finally got my '42' answer.

Here the final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "Python.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
   Py_Initialize();

   PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *presult;
   // Initialize the Python Interpreter

   // Build the name object
   pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"exp.main");

   // Load the module object
   pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);


   // pDict is a borrowed reference 
   pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);


   // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
   pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, (char*)"entry_point");

   presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);

   // Py_DECREF(pValue);

   // Clean up
   Py_DECREF(pModule);
   Py_DECREF(pName);
   Py_Finalize();
}
```

(Craig pointed out that executable file might not finish by '.o', learn more: [What is *.o file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186246/what-is-o-file))
So, the new compile command is:

```
g++ -Wall -I~/miniconda3/include/python3.9 run.cpp -L~/miniconda3/lib -lpython3.9 -o run
```

Comment: You're missing any kind of error checking

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding me, I forgot error checking. (This code was not the final code I will use but I should have put it anyway ;) )